# Always choose larger file for duplicate downloads in Jdownloader2?

Tags: download, duplicate, dialog, overwrite, jdownloader

I am downloading a very large number of image links in Jdownloader2 (hundreds at a time.) It has to parse each URL to get the images, and it always finds thumbnails as well, which have the same filename as the full size images.

I can use linkgrabber filesize filter to remove some of the thumbnails, but the size variance between both the thumbnails and full images is such that I cannot use that to remove all thumbnails (the thumbnail for any particular image is smaller than that image, but some full size images are smaller than other thumbnails.)

As a result, when a duplicate filename invariably downloads, JDownloader asks me if I want to keep the current file or overwrite it. Sometimes it downloads the full size image (larger) first, in which case I want to keep the current file. Sometimes it downloads the thumbnail (smaller) file first, in which case I need to overwrite the current file.

By the way, each url creates a seperate package name, so I can't choose rename file and check "remember for this package."

Is there anyway to either set rename file as the default option for all cases, or set it to prefer the larger file in each case, so it stops asking that question? That way I dont have to monitor the download for hours and and answer the same question hundreds times, with potentially a different answer for each question!

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to "auto rename" if the file already exists. This will prevent the pop up to decide for each file.

Open settings by pressing CTRL+P

In "General", under "Download Management", there is the option of changing this setting at the very bottom.